# Using toggle in for loop

Tags: jquery, html, django, django-models, django-templates

In my Django template, I am retrieving the data from DB and displaying it in table format using for loop. Now, when I click on "Name" field, I want to show some data of that person. Initially, while displaying, only the table should be visible, which means the data of the particular person should remain hide and when I click on that person's name, the information about that person should be shown. Now, I have 2 problems. 1st is, when I click on any name, the information about all the persons gets displayed. For example, if there are 3 entries in my DB and if I click on the name of any person than the information about all the 3 people will get displayed. I just want to display the information of the person on which I clicked on. And the second problem is that after clicking on the name, the data is displayed on the top of the table. I want that suppose I am clicking on the second row, then the information should be displayed below the 2nd row and above the 3rd row.

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <th>id</th>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Status</th>
  </tr>

  {% for records in obj %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{records.id}}</td>
    <td class="pop">{{records.name}}</td>
     <div class="dashboard">
                <div>
                <p>Toggled</p>
                </div>
     </div>
    <td>{{records.status}}</td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

And here the script for toggle:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".pop").click(function(){
        $(".dashboard").toggle();
});
});
```

I also tried the following solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".pop").click(function(e){

        $(this).nextall(".dashboard:lt(e)").toggle();

    });
    });
```

But, it didn't work.

Comment: Hi Solanki Ketul, Please post in html instead of django

Comment: you call using pop as id but calling class instead

Comment: @KrishnaJonnalagadda Still the issue remains.....

Answer (score 0):

replace your id pop as class

```js
    $(function(){
        $('.pop').click(function(){
            $(this).closest('tr').siblings().toggle();
        })
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
          <thead>

  <tr>
   <th>id</th>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Status</th>
   <th>Status 2</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="pop">User</td>
     <td><div class="dashboard">
                <div>
                <p>Toggled 1</p>
                </div>
     </div></td>
    <td>Active true 1</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td class="pop">User 2</td>
     <td><div class="dashboard">
                <div>
                <p>Toggled 2</p>
                </div>
     </div></td>
    <td>Active true 2</td>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td class="pop">User 3</td>
     <td><div class="dashboard">
                <div>
                <p>Toggled 3</p>
                </div>
     </div></td>
    <td>Active true 3</td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: Actually I am using a for loop and there are a lot of rows in DB which I have to retrieve.